# I deleted Apache and I can't reinstall it

Tags: 16.04, apache2

It's very important because my server is my shop and my job.

I had a problem when I tried to install VirtualHost then I tried to reinstall Apache, however I have some problems because it seems my version of Ubuntu is obsolete. I tried many things but nothing worked.

`sudo apt-get install` does not find the sources to install apache2.

The actual error is:

```
$ sudo apt install apache2  

Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
Package apache2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.  
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'apache2' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Show us the output of `apt-cache policy apache2 apache2-bin` and the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.  Also indicate which Ubuntu version you are using.

Comment: apache2:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
apache2-bin:
  Installed: 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.4
  Candidate: 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.4
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Comment: Hi @Quentin, please move output of apt-cache above to your main post. To be clear: you should complete your post with (1) your Ubuntu version (2) two commands outputs from Thomas Ward above (3) your command to remove said apache2.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.... I finally paid someone to fix the problem. I don't rally know how he fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo tasksel` and selecting `LAMP` from the list. It will automate the setup and installation of Apache2, MySQL and PHP.

The reason that `sudo apt install apache2` doesn't work for you is because that's not technically a real package. It's a "placeholder" package that other packages can rely on because apache2 actually has many different ways it can be installed (prefork, suexec, cgi, etc.)

Comment: I do not have LAMP in the list.

Comment: [ ] Manual package selection                                     │ 
    │    [*] DNS server                                                   │ 
    │    [*] Mail server                                                  │ 
    │    [*] OpenSSH server

Comment: That is strange you should have a large list and you can use the arrow keys to navigate it: https://i.imgur.com/pc4XVl7.png

Comment: I only have 4 options :/

Comment: Have you tried navigating to `http://localhost` and seeing or running `service apache2 status`? You do have `apache2-bin` installed so it should be running.